# Would be that it would be

Tags: sentence-patterns

Is anything wrong with saying "My guess would be that it would be nice"?

I feel that the "would be that it would be" part sounds wrong somehow but I can't quite put my finger on why.

Comment: It's a bit convoluted, but there's nothing "wrong" with it, and it's perfectly understandable to an E1L listener.

Comment: @HotLicks - What's *E1L*?

Comment: @aparente001 - Like E2L only different -- English as your first language rather than your second.

Answer (score 3):

*Would* gives the modal aspect of uncertainty, so if you're sure of what your guess would be, but you're not sure of whether you'd like the situation, you'd say

> My guess is that it would be nice.

If you're not even sure of what you'd guess, you'd say

> My guess would be [if you forced me to guess] that it would be nice.

The reason the latter sounds a bit "wrong" is that a guess already asserts uncertainty.